# How to keep an image constantly in corner of page, but no longer visible when scrolling down?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with the following code applied to it:

```
<div id="container" style="position:fixed;right:0px;top:27px;">
```

This keeps the image in the top right corner of my page, no matter how much I zoom in or out, which is what I expect. The issue is, because it's position is fixed, when I scroll down the image also moves down the page. I want it to stay in that top right corner of my page when zooming in and out, but without it folowing me when I scroll down.

A good example of this is when one goes onto Google, and has the 'Sign in' button which does what my image currently does, but doesn't follow the user if the scroll down (may have to zoom in to scroll down). I tried looking at Google's source code, but I believe they import an external CSS file.

If anyone could help me resolve this, I'd appreciate it greatly.

UPDATE: Here's the code after attempting position:absolute

```
<div style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:10px;">
<img class="box1" src="a src" alt="an alt" title="a title">
    <div class="box2">
        <a href="#" style="padding:21.6px 8.5px 7px 8px;background-color:#ffa939;"><img
    src="a src" alt="an alt" style="width:45px;height:27px;" title="a title"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS

```
.box1 {
width:45px;
height:27px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
}


.box2 {
visibility:hidden;
position:relative;
top:5px;
right:8px;
width:65.5px;
margin:0px;
border:0px;
}
```

Ignore the old code. With this code, my image is no longer visible on the page no matter how far in or out I zoom. I tried using left to position it, but when zooming out it doesn't stay in that fixed screen position.

Comment: `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Rockerest  
I have tried, but I don't believe this keeps my image constantly in the top right corner when I zoom out/in.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/kmptwdvv/ Then something else is affecting your page. Part of the requirements of a question on Stack Overflow are a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which means that the problem must be reproduced in the question itself using the absolute minimum code to reproduce _the problem_ (i.e., not your whole site, but reproduce the problem itself).

Comment: @rockerest Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute instead.
Unlike fixed position, it is affected by page scroll.

Comment: I have tried, but I don't believe this keeps my image constantly in the top right corner when I zoom out/in.

Answer (score 0):

The following puts the selected image at the top-right corner and keeps it there. Put the div container wherever it fits. In fact, it can even be the last thing before the closing body tag and still produce the top-right image. Change to suit your needs, e.g. width, height, or have a look at calc().

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgi {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("bgi.jpg");
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="bgi"></div>
```

Comment: I have already accomplished this as clearly stated, I want to prevent that image from following me as I scroll down a page, how would I do that? It stays in the top right corner, but when I scroll down the page it remains in its exact position (not relative to monitor) so that I no longer see it.